# Best online reading to understand .NET Code Access Security?

Tags: .net, security, code-access-security

I'm thinking about learning CAS, but I need to quickly grasp basic architecture, performance implications and if it at all suits my needs. What should I read?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566934/is-code-access-security-of-any-real-world-use/1567416#1567416

Answer (score 2):

MSDN itself provides the info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/930b76w0(VS.71).aspx).

You also can refer to [patterns and practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302424.aspx) advocated by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

There is one very important thing to remember with CAS: a lot of code (too much code) runs at full trust. And with full trust, most of CAS is silently ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Keith Brown's book is insanely good, and it's online.  I suggest buying a copy as well.  IMO it's a must-read for every .NET developer :

[The .NET Developer's Guide to Windows Security](http://alt.pluralsight.com/wiki/default.aspx/Keith.GuideBook/HomePage.html)