# Problems with the .NET Framework version

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, ftp, .net-framework-version

I have an ASP.Net MVC 5 application and WebApi, in .NET version 4.5.2 and post them to my FTP server I have the following error (attached image) ...

And asking the company's technical support, they answered the following:

> From the .Net Framework 4.0, Microsoft has modified an internal
>   component of the so-called CAS (Code Access Security), which
>   determines how classes can access one others.
>
> In order for your application to be functional on our servers, you
>   will need to have the following three items:
>
> - Medium trust
> - MVC4
> - Integrated

Is there any way to make my current project have these specifications without having to create another project?

[Error.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lr2s.png)

Comment: I think you forgot to post the error. You should [edit] your question to fix that. And note that text is generally preferred over a screenshot if the error is presented as text.

Comment: mmm sorry ..but if you're using MVC5 .. you're using .NET CORE?? is it?

Answer (score 0):

For first point, have you checked out [that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee941656(v=vs.100).aspx) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566934/is-code-access-security-of-any-real-world-use) posts?
For second, you need to update framework and MVC versions to appropriate on your hosting